# RestTemplate on Java got timeout error but on Postman it is okay

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, resttemplate

I am currently trying to use a service to send a WhatsApp message.
Here is **my snippet** of code:

```java
String url = "https://[service-url].com/[rest-of-the-path]"
String username = "username"
String password = "password"
String auth = username + ":" + password
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(){{
     set("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
}};
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(5000);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, headers, String.class);
```

When I run this program, the code got an error with the message of connection timed out error when it tries to `postForObject`. I tried to googled and it says that firewall/proxy could be the issues. However, if that is the case - When I tried using the same url with the same username and password as the basic authentication on Postman, I got the result that I desired. If it is indeed due to the proxy issues, shouldn't Postman give me the same error? So I believe that the error might be somewhere else that I am not aware of.

Can someone points out where did I go wrong on this one?

**Edit:** I have tried various alternative like using `Unirest` or `HttpUrlConnection` it gives me the same problem which is connection timed out whenever it tries to connect to the url. There was some article suggest that the service could be overloaded so it got a timeout error but I tried doing it through my java localhost and hit directly to the url through postman at almost similar time - the java localhost gives me an error meanwhile when I hit directly to the url through postman it works as intended

**Edit** I forgot to mention that I am using java 8 and for some reasons, I can't upgrade to to later version

Comment: Share your postman response details. How much time it is taking

Comment: This is my response details on postman when hitting the targeted url directly (https://i.imgur.com/neC4HOZ.png) it only take me 570ms

Comment: Is it possible there is a firewall that block from http localhost request to https url?